# Gradle refresh removes source folders in build path

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I imported an already existing **gradle** project and everything works fine, but when I refresh the gradle source folders from **eclipse** both folders *src* and *test* are removed from the build path and the classes used in the test folder are not found anymore.

I tried importing it as a java and gradle project but nothing worked so far. Also changing the build.gradle main sourceSets to *srcDirs = "src"* didn't help either.

This is my *build.gradle* which is exactly the same one of the original project.

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '/src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir '/src'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["test"]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+' 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was edit the .classpath file in the project root:

```
...
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="FROM_GRADLE_MODEL" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
...
```

set the "path" attribute in the "classpathentry" node to the appropriate value.