# Why does Gradle->Refresh remove my protobuf source folder from .classpath?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have an Eclipse/Gradle project that looks like the following. One directory for `.proto` descriptors and one directory for the generated `.java` files for inclusion in other projects.

```
    src/main/java
    src/main/proto
```

I want to add my `src/main/proto` directory as an Eclipse source folder to make editing easier.

So naturally I add `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/proto"/>` to my `.classpath` file. The source folder is added and everything is great until I run `Gradle->Refresh` which unkindly removes the source folder. My guess is that Gradle doesn't find any `.java` files in the `proto` folder and therefore removes the entire folder from `.classpath`. Is there any way to prevent this?

I have also tried:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/proto">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="FROM_GRADLE_MODEL" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869664/gradle-refresh-removes-source-folders-in-build-path) without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so the thing is that gradle will (re)-generate the .classpath file from scratch if you do the refresh. So anything you haven't defined at the gradle level will be lost!

How do you define the src folders in Gradle ?
Try to put the following block into you build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/proto'
        }
    }
}
```

This should add 'src/main/proto' to the eclipse classpath as long as the folder contain at least one file!